# Is findAllSorted automatically updated like findAll in Realm DB

Tags: android, sorting, realm

I have Realm DB in my Android app and I use realm-recyclerview:

https://github.com/thorbenprimke/realm-recyclerview

Now I am trying to sort my RecyclerView using the Customized pattern.

ِAnd after I thought about it, I decided to sort the RealmResults, not the RecyclerView.

Is there better way to sort a RecyclerView?

My question is: will findAllSorted get automatically updated like findAll?
If yes, is it automatically sorted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, both methods will return a `RealmResults` object which is updated automatically as the Realm changes. And if the Realm is updated, the results will automatically be sorted.

> According to the [Realm documentation](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmResults.html):
>
> RealmResults are live views, which means that if it is on an Looper thread, it will automatically update its query results after a transaction has been committed.

See: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmQuery.html#findAllSorted-java.lang.String-
See: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmResults.html